# DirectShow can't recognize my video capture device

Tags: video, filter, device, directshow, capture

I have video capture device that I know can be recognized by directshow.

Currently, I am running Windows 10 x64 and everything is fine, directshow recongizes
my video capture device.

Recently, I changed my OS to Windows 10 x86 and I can't get directshow recognize my capture device.
For the x64 I had directshow filter dll which I register with regsvr32 and then my capture device is recognized by directshow).

The problem is the filter dll compiled for x64 therefore I can't use it on the x86 and I don't have the filter source code (I can't ask the vendor for the filter).

Can anyone guide me what should I do?

Comment: There is nothing you can do on 32-bit OS with just 64-bit implementation of DirectShow filter.

Comment: I am aware of that. I thought about implementing the filter my self, but unfortunately I don't know where to start.